# Can Perlin Noise create a 2D map that would have water (low noise values) around the corners?

Tags: procedural

I have been prototyping a 2D procedural map for the past days. The terrain generates fine, but the goal would be also to have water around the edges of the world. So basically low noise values. I have tried to manually shift the values around the edges but some seeds will generate a solid mountain range on one side like the image shows. If I create a gradient on the top side of the image, I will still end up with a straight line. It will look very unnatural. Is there a way to generate noise with low values toward the edges? TY[image]